# NameError: name 'category_index' is not defined, how to fix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I've tried to run a real-time object detection program  but it gives me this error.

NameError: name 'category_index' is not defined

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

while cap.isOpened(): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)
    
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
    
    num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
    detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                  for key, value in detections.items()}
    detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=5,
                min_score_thresh=.8,
                agnostic_mode=False)

    cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please post your code instead of the screenshot of the error please?

Comment: Sorry Just posted now

Answer (score 1):

you can add this line as a placeholder to bypass the error

> category_index ={'name':'dummyname','id':1}

Comment: Does this command have to do with the number of the classes I have? For instance if I have 10 classes, is the above command the same?

Comment: Yes the category_index is used as a label map , so if you want to classify 10 classes then you have to provide 10 name and id.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an undeclared variable `category_index` in `viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` function call.

Python's `NameError` is an [exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError) raised when a local or global name is not found.
You need to make sure to *declare* any variable before using it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution is to run this before the code

`category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(files['LABELMAP'])`